# Wordpress 404 error message

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I have a tryit yourself editor on my wordpress site. The issue is: if I enter html tags in the "SOURCE CODE" field, and submit the form, I get a 404:not found error. But if I enter just plain text or leave the field empty, everything works just fine. Is there something I am getting wrong? You can check it out here: http://www.naijaprogrammer.com/tryit/

There are 2 files: tryview_sc.php and index.php : code in tryview_sc.php is:

```
if(isset($_POST['code']))
{
    echo $_POST['code'];
    exit;
}
else if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $dash=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
    $file_query=mysql_query("SELECT code FROM editor WHERE id='$dash'");
    $count=mysql_num_rows($file_query);
    if($count==0)
    {
        return;
    }
    else{
        $file=mysql_fetch_array($file_query);
        echo $file['code'];
    }
}
else
{
    return;
}
```

The code you'd be interested in the index.php file is:

```
<form action="tryview_sc.php" method="post" target="view" id="tryitform" name="tryitform">
     <textarea class="code_input" id="pre_code" wrap="logical"><?php echo $output; ?></textarea>
     <input type="hidden" name="code" id="code" />
     <input type="hidden" id="bt" name="bt" />
    </form>
```

and this iframe: `<iframe style="background-color:#fff;" class="result_output" frameborder="0" name="view" src="tryview_sc.php">`

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: There are 2 files: tryview_sc.php and index.php

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working ok for some HTML tags (e.g. <b>test</b> works fine).

Your javascript code is storing the "source code" in the value of a hidden form element. This won't work well with some characters in the source code, particularly "

You need to encode the source code in the Javascript with encodeURIComponent() then decode it in the PHP script with rawurldecode().

See here for more details: [encodeURIComponent()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp), [rawurldecode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php)